# javascript fetch never reaches the POST request on nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to post some data to my nodejs server using fetch api but it seems the fetch request never reaches my server..

Fetch code

```
const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/students/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: `{
    "name": "Ahmed",
    "seat": 4
  }`
});
console.log(resp);

const json = await resp.json();
return json;
```

nodeJS post body

```
route.post("/", CORS, async (req, res) => {
console.log('abc', req.body);

const {
    error
} = validateStudent(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
const result = await addStudent(req.body);
if (!result) return res.status(400).send("Student cannot be added");
res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

code of CORS middleware

```
console.log('avcx');

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
console.log('acvced');

next();
```

As you can see I've done some logs on my server but nothing shows up... BTW eveything is working fine with get request..

sending the same request with postman works fine.

I don't know why I'm getting this error I tackled this error for GET requests by creating a middleware 'CORS' but I'm still getting this error for POST request:-
[image: I don't know why I'm getting this error I tackled this error for GET requests by creating a middleware 'CORS' but I'm still getting this error for POST request]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I get an error of No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource so I created the CORs middleware and now I am not getting that error..

Comment: @Bergi There absolutely is -- for example, if your script is served through the `file` protocol, where every URI is normally a *distinct* origin -- every [HTTP/HTTPS] request to `localhost` will be preflighted and user agent will expect CORS headers. Same story when script served by `localhost` over HTTP attempts to fetch resources at `localhost` over HTTPS, and vice versa. `localhost` by and large, benefits from no special treatment here. To put this in context (I am sure you had one), if their backend is listening on a port that is different from `5000`, it's its own origin, again.

Comment: Your middleware would need to answer `OPTIONS` requests, not `POST` ones.

Comment: You need to add information to your question -- *what* executes the code with the `fetch` call? On what interface and port is your Node.js service listening? Since you have "middleware" (I'd call it a proxy HTTP server myself), more importantly, on what interface and port is that "middleware" listening? Or are both the same service, just different functions? If CORS has any effect, there will be an `OPTIONS` request, and if you don't handle it properly, no `POST` will be made at all (if your user agent subjects your script to CORS treatment).

Comment: I didn't know about that particular issue, but a bug in Chrome wouldn't be my guiding light here. I use Firefox myself, and I seem to remember dealing with the effect of contacting `localhost` from a script served over both `file` protocol and from another origin with `localhost` as hostname, just last week. I will try to get back to you on this one. Regardless, I don't remember `localhost` being mentioned for special treatment in any CORS literature I have read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I wasn't handling the incoming requests correctly because I didn't know that fetch sends a **preflight request with an OPTION method** before sending the actual POST request. So I solved it by adding this line in my index file above every other request which will be executed every time a request (with any method) is made.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", " GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");

next();
});
```